# Should I have concern about datastoreRpcErrors?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-dataflow

When I run dataflow jobs that writes to google cloud datastore, sometime I see the metrics show that I had one or two `datastoreRpcErrors`:

[image]

Since these datastore writes usually contain a batch of keys, I am wondering in the situation of RpcError, if some retry will happen automatically. If not, what would be a good way to handle these cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr**: By default `datastoreRpcErrors` will use 5 retries automatically.

I dig into the code of [`datastoreio`](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/gcp/datastore/v1/datastoreio.py) in beam python sdk. It looks like the final entity mutations are flushed in batch via `DatastoreWriteFn()`.

```
# Flush the current batch of mutations to Cloud Datastore.
_, latency_ms = helper.write_mutations(
    self._datastore, self._project, self._mutations,
    self._throttler, self._update_rpc_stats,
    throttle_delay=_Mutate._WRITE_BATCH_TARGET_LATENCY_MS/1000)
```

The RPCError is caught by this block of code in `write_mutations` in the [`helper`](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/gcp/datastore/v1/helper.py); and there is a decorator `@retry.with_exponential_backoff` for `commit` method; and the default number of retry is set to 5; `retry_on_rpc_error` defines the concrete `RPCError` and `SocketError` reasons to trigger retry.

```
for mutation in mutations:
  commit_request.mutations.add().CopyFrom(mutation)
  @retry.with_exponential_backoff(num_retries=5,
                                  retry_filter=retry_on_rpc_error)
  def commit(request):
    # Client-side throttling.
    while throttler.throttle_request(time.time()*1000):
    try:
      response = datastore.commit(request)
      ...
    except (RPCError, SocketError):
      if rpc_stats_callback:
        rpc_stats_callback(errors=1)
      raise
      ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should first of all determine which kind of error occurred in order to see what are your options.

However, in the official Datastore documentation, there is a list of all the possible [errors and their error codes](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/errors#error_codes) . Fortunately, they come with recommended actions for each.

My advice is that your implement their recommendations and see for alternatives if they are not effective for you